# search_choices flutter package has border field?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

im using searchchoices.single to search and use in dropdown but i cant give border to the search choices without wrapping it to the container

SearchChoices.single(

```
                     items: tyreserialno.map((category) => DropdownMenuItem(

                       value: category,
                       child: Text(category.name),
                     )).toList(),
                     value: _selectedtyrserialnoCategory,
                     hint: "Select Tyre Serial No",
                     searchHint: "Search for Tyre Serial No",
                     onChanged: (value) {
                       setState(() {
                         _selectedtyrserialnoCategory = value;
                         tyreserialnoid = value?.id;
                       });
                     },
                     isExpanded: true,
                   ), i want to give decoration border function to give inside searchchoice howtogive i dont want to wrap it with container
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.